# How to monitor OPTIMIZE process in Clickhouse?

Tags: clickhouse

Adding a materialized column

```
ALTER TABLE actions ADD COLUMN `total` UInt64 MATERIALIZED price1 + price2
```

Requires running `OPTIMIZE` on table

```
OPTIMIZE TABLE actions FINAL
```

`OPTIMIZE` is a slow process, how can I monitor this process?

Answer (score 1):

```
select * from system.merges where table = 'actions'
```